# How to implement ui-sortable with *ngFor in angular 2?

Tags: angular, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I am implementing ui-sortable to a ul using *nFor to repeat li items using a object which is loaded from a server. I tried doing this using jquery ui but all I an do is just sort html but not object used in *ngFor. Can someone please show me a plunk or sample technique to achieve this?

Comment: did you find your answer?